# How to test for database availability in c# script task for an oledb connection

Tags: c#, ssis

I have to check for database availability using c# scripting for an "oledb" connection in an ssis package.

Since my connection is oledb I'm not able to use AcquireConnection method.

I tried using ConnectionString property of ConnectionManager but I get the connection string even when database is offline.

Any idea how to go about with unmanaged Objects here oledb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the complete documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

what you may need to test the oledb connection is then something like this:

```
    string connectionString =
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
        + "c:\\Data\\Northwind.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;";

    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return true;
```